# How to move event to another calendar in one account?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I'm integrating Outlook calendar to my app and I want my user can change their events from this calendar to another calendar (like changing from `Calendar` to `calendar2` in the origin Outlook calendar).

But I can't find any endpoint to do this, even the `UpdateEvent` endpoint in their docs doesn't support this.

So how can I change event's calendar using MS graph API ? Right now the only way I'm thinking of is delete the old event in `Calendar` and create new event in `calendar2` which is not 100% reliable because sometimes the delete or create request can failed

[image])

Answer (score 1):

Currently the is no way to move an event to another calendar. You can add a feature request [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that the engineering team may implement it in future.

So far as you said the only way may be delete then create but also keep in mind that the create should add all the existing properties/data like extensions when creating in the new calendar.